# Filling Blank values from value from above in Qlik Sense?

Tags: loading, qliksense, blank-line

Qlik Sense is a BI tool in which I need to fill the blank values with a value from above

[image]
*(image from this related [thread](https://community.qlik.com/thread/96702))*

The solution in Qlik View is the following by this [thread](https://community.qlik.com/thread/96702) but in Qlik Sense, it only fills one value below the above value.

```
if(len(trim("Date"))=0, peek("Date"), "Date") as Date1, 
if("Date"= ' ' or "Date"= '' or  isnull ("Date"),  Previous("Date"),"Date") as Date11,
```

So how can I fill the blanks with the Dates `01.01.2013` for values 45, 213 and 688; and `02.01.2013` for 3232, 578 and 64421.

**Small working example that does not work**

```
Dataaaaa:
Load
    if( len( trim([Date 1]) ) = 0, peek([Date 1]), [Date 1])  as Datee,
    if( len( trim(Dat) ) = 0, peek(Dat), Dat) as DateII
;
Load * Inline [
    Date 1      , Dat   ,   Value11, Value22,
    'Hello'     , 'ha'  ,   20    , 30
    ''          ,       ,   45    , 321,
    ''          ,       ,   213   , 23
    ''          ,       ,   678   , 798
    'No Word'   , 'he'  ,   123   , 123
    ''          ,       ,   3232  , 3232
    ''          ,       ,   578   , 953
    ''          ,       ,   64421 , 7655
];
```

### **How does the filling of the blanks work in the Data Load Editor of Qlik Sense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the script below both fields `Date` and `Date1` will be filled. `Date1` is just an example how this can be achieved in a new field.

Btw QlikView v12 and Qlik Sense have the same engine in the background so there shouldn't be any difference where the script is running.

```
Data:
Load
//  Date,
    Value1,
    Value2,
    if( len( trim(Date) ) = 0, peek(Date), Date)  as Date,
    if( len( trim(Date) ) = 0, peek(Date1), Date) as Date1
;
Load * Inline [
    Date        , Value1, Value2,
    '01.01.2013', 20    , 30
    ''          , 45    , 321,
    ''          , 213   , 23
    ''          , 678   , 798
    '02.02.2013', 123   , 123
    ''          , 3232  , 3232
    ''          , 578   , 953
    ''          , 64421 , 7655
];
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What about if you have spaces in the column names? Do you have to escape the spaces or quotes or something else? I can get this working but struggling with spaces in the column names.

Comment: I updated the question with a small working example that does not work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46078284/164148), I can get your example working but not slightly modified versions of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the non-working example getting work like the below. The **peek** command refers to the ongoing column, not the inline column, hence the corrections.

```
Dataaaaa:
Load
    if( len( trim([Date 1]) ) = 0, peek(Datee), [Date 1])  as Datee,
    if( len( trim(Dat) ) = 0, peek(DateII), Dat) as DateII
;
Load * Inline [
    Date 1      , Dat   ,   Value11, Value22,
    'Hello'     , 'ha'  ,   20    , 30
    ''          ,       ,   45    , 321,
    ''          ,       ,   213   , 23
    ''          ,       ,   678   , 798
    'No Word'   , 'he'  ,   123   , 123
    ''          ,       ,   3232  , 3232
    ''          ,       ,   578   , 953
    ''          ,       ,   64421 , 7655
];
```

Further information in [**preceding load**](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/2.1/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/preceding-load.htm).